# What is the idiomatic way to get a virtual method reference?

Tags: python

I am using Python to build a parser for a file format that has many types of small chunks. Although I expect my own parsing to be sufficient, I'd like to let clients subclass the parser class to provide custom behavior if they need to.

In C++, I could write something like this:

```
enum ChunkTypes {
    CHUNK_FOO,
    CHUNK_BAR,
    CHUNK_BAZ,
};

class Parser {
public:
    virtual void parse_foo(size_t offset);
    virtual void parse_bar(size_t offset);
    virtual void parse_baz(size_t offset);
};

typedef void (Parser::*parse_method[])(size_t);
parse_method methods[] = {
    &Parser::parse_foo,
    &Parser::parse_bar,
    &Parser::parse_baz,
};

Parser& parser = get_parser();
while (has_more_chunks())
{
    parse_method method = methods[chunk_type()];
    size_t chunk_offset = get_chunk_offset();
    (parser.*method)(chunk_offset);
}
```

As this might not be familiar to people who don't write a lot of C++: `parse_method`, in this example, is a "pointer-to-member" to a `Parser` method which accepts a `size_t` argument. `(parser.*method)(chunk_offset)` applies the method `method` to `parser` and passes it the `chunk_offset` parameter. Note that **this respects virtual dispatch**: with a subclass of `Parser` that overrides `parse_foo`, `(parser.*method)(chunk_offset)` (when `method` is `parse_foo`), the subclass's implementation will be called.

In Python, I can write something like this:

```
class Parser:
    def parse_foo(self, offset):
        # ...

    def parse_bar(self, offset):
        # ...

    def parse_baz(self, offset):
        # ...

methods = [
    Parser.parse_foo,
    Parser.parse_bar,
    Parser.parse_baz]

parser = get_parser()
while has_more_chunks():
    method = methods[chunk_type()]
    offset = get_chunk_offset()
    method(parser, offset)
```

However, `Parser.parse_foo` is a reference to `Parser`'s implementation of `parse_foo`, specifically. Even if I call it on a subclass of `Parser` that overrides it, what is called is still the original implementation.

Is there a way, in Python, to get a "method reference" that respects virtual dispatch? I can make per-instance tables that use `self.parse_foo`, but that seems wasteful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing to a method reference is basically just a string containing the method's name. You can use that name to look up the method on the parser object with [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) and then call it:

```
methods = [
    'parse_foo',
    'parse_bar',
    'parse_baz'
]

parser = get_parser()
while has_more_chunks():
    method_name = methods[chunk_type()]
    method = getattr(parser, method_name)  # get the method
    offset = get_chunk_offset()
    method(offset)  # call the bound method we retrieved earlier
```

Alternatively, you can use proxy functions that call the corresponding methods:

```
methods = [
    lambda parser, offset: parser.parse_foo(offset),
    lambda parser, offset: parser.parse_bar(offset),
    lambda parser, offset: parser.parse_baz(offset)
]

parser = get_parser()
while has_more_chunks():
    method = methods[chunk_type()]
    offset = get_chunk_offset()
    method(parser, offset)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bound method, but the performance overhead is pretty minimal:

```
methods = [
    lambda parser, offset: parser.parse_foo(offset),
    lambda parser, offset: parser.parse_bar(offset),
    ...]
```

If you don't want to be tied to a specific argument signature, you can write:

```
lambda parser, *args, **kwargs: parser.parse_foo(*args, **kwargs)
```

Better yet, if `chunk_type()` returns a string such as `parse_foo`, you can just write:

```
getattr(parser, chunk_type())(offset)
```

without the list of methods at all.

Answer (score 0):

So you would use pointer to members in C++. The closest in Python would be to have an instance attribute that will receive a bound method. Here is some code demonstrating it:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name  # instance identification
    # the methods
    def parse_foo(self, offset):
        print("in foo for instance {} with offset {}".format(
            self.name, offset))
    def parse_bar(self, offset):
        print("in bar for instance {} with offset {}".format(
            self.name, offset))
    def parse_baz(self, offset):
        print("in baz for instance {} with offset {}".format(
            self.name, offset))
    # an array of unbound methods
    methods = [ parse_foo, parse_bar, parse_baz ]

a = A("id_1")         # creates an A instance
a.method = getattr(a, A.methods[1].__name__)   # have a.method be a bound parse_bar method
a.method(10)
```

prints as expected:

```
in bar for instance id_1 with offset 10
```

This allows different instances of A to have `a.method(offset)` invoke different methods.

---

Anyway, as you are asking for an *idiomatic* way, this is not very Pythonic. But what is not Pythonic is a dispatcher on an integer (the enum or index array) while Python natively allows to dispatch by names:

```
a.method = getattr(a, "parse_baz")
a.method(5)
```

outputs

```
in baz for instance id_1 with offset 5
```